# spring boot compression doesn't work

Tags: java, http, tomcat, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a **spring boot** based application. I want to download a huge amount of data from a database as a text file through REST API.
Since the amount of data might be really huge, let's say at least 1_000_000 enries, I decided to use Stream provided by Java 8 (fortunately Spring DATA JPA allows streaming queries)

It works fine but I'd like to compress the downloaded result. I know that Tomcat provides such functionality [as mentioned here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-servlet-containers.html#how-to-enable-http-response-compression).

But for some reasons the result file is not compressed. Can't find out what I'm doing wrong.

Take a look at the code that I've written so far:

**Model**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Integer age;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String name, Integer age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", age=" + age +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**DAO Layer**

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT u from User u")
    @QueryHints(value = @QueryHint(name = HINT_FETCH_SIZE, value = "" + Integer.MIN_VALUE))
    Stream<User> streamAll();

}
```

**And finally Rest Controller**

```
@RestController
public class DownloadController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/stream", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public void stream(HttpServletResponse response) {

        response.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
        response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

        try(Stream<User> users = userRepository.streamAll()) {
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

            users.forEach(u -> {
                out.write(u.toString());
                out.write("\n");
                entityManager.detach(u);
            });

            out.flush();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Exception occurred while exporting results", e);
        }
    }

}
```

In the **application.properties** file I added `server.compression.enabled=true` and since I have set header `"Content-Type", "text/plain"` I guess it should be compressed by default [as mentioned here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-servlet-containers.html#how-to-enable-http-response-compression).

Any ideas would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens if you set the content type using setContentType()? Also, how do you determine that the response is not compressed? If you expect to get a gzipped file as a result, you won't. The bytes will be compressed on the network, and the browser will decompress them, and save the original, text file.

Comment: @JB Nizet, thank you for your answer. Is there a way how to prevent this behavior do not allow to decompress the final result. In other words I just want it to be zipped after downloading. Regarding setting content type I didn't quite get what you meant? Should I set it? Cause I thought that setting content-type as I do in my rest controller is quite enough.

Comment: For the second part, HttpServletResponse has a setContentType() method. For the first part, you don't want to send a text file then. You want to send a gzip file. Set the content type to application/x-gzip, wrap the response output stream into a GZIPOutpurStream, and write your text to this GZIPOutputStream.

Comment: sounds great, thank you for your help!